# Sending a GET request in SSJC using java.net.URL

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have code in the afterRenderReponse event in an xpage (xagent) to establish a connection with the Domino Data Service and return the result (json) to a scoped variable.

Anonymous access to the database containing the xpage is No Access, so the user will have to log in.

Problem is that when calling url.openConnection() in the code, the login form is returned. Meaning I have to authenticate again even if the requested url is at the same server/domain as the xpage calling it.

I know I can authenticate using basic authentication using:
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc) , but then I would have to know the username and password + base64 encode this.

My question is : Since the user is allready authenticated, is it possible to "pass along" these credentials to the java.net.HttpURLConnection object ? Is it possible to get a handle to the ltpatoken cookie and provide this ? Any other way ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">

        <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:// Establish connection with Domino database collection resource

try{
    var url = new java.net.URL("http://server/mydb.nsf/api/data");

    var conn:java.net.HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() == "200") {



        // Get the response

        var reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        var buffer = new java.lang.StringBuffer();

        var line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            buffer.append(line);

        }

        reader.close();



        // Create array from response

        var jsonarray = eval('(' + buffer + ')');



        // Get filenames and titles from Domino database collection resource

        // On XPage, requestScope.status is bound to a multi-line text control

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i++) {

            requestScope.status += jsonarray [i].@filepath + " - " + jsonarray [i].@title + "\n";

        }



    } else { // if connection fails

        requestScope.status = conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage();

    }  
    } catch(e){
  _dump(e);
}
    }]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
    </xp:view>
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks !

Best regards,
Petter Kjeilen

Answer (score 2):

If the user is authenticated and you're using session authentication on the server, you can read the session cookies from the users and pass the same cookies along with subsequent (GET) requests.

Depending on how session authentication is configured on the Domino server, you're looking for the **DomAuthSessionId** or **LTPAToken** cookie. Have a look at the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) page for a sample on how to read the cookies and send them along with additional requests ("maintaining the session" section).

Comment: The link refers to this question.

Comment: @Mark - The link you are refering to is pointing to this question. Please update the link.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an HTTP URL Connection! Too much headache. Use the Apache HTTP Client. The classes are on the Domino server. Use [this](https://www.wissel.net/blog/downloads/2010/HTTPReader.java) as a reference point how to use it.

Comment: I'm looking into your HTTPReader wrapper class. Looks good for my need, but I can see that support for SSO is not implemented (doSSOLogin method). Is there a newer version of the class where this is implemented ? :-)

Comment: nope, didn't have time for that. But it shouldn't be too hard --> you need to set a cookie and the user session gives you access to that value

Comment: the link is dead 404 message

Comment: fixed link. Try now